# Getting file access permission in a folder in Android 11/12

Tags: android, file-access

My app will read and write .db and .txt files in a directory in Downloads.

I already select and request that folder access permission like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_FOR_DIR);
```

It works fine if the directory is empty and create those files from app.

If I want to read or edit those files already exist will cause error:

```
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Download/app_Folder/test.txt: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

I'm trying not to ask ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION.

How to let my app access those already exist files without using file selector?